# update nested Object in Array in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I am stuck in a query i would like to create. Let's assume I have the following Documents in a random collection:

```
[
    {
        "name":"Max",
        "cars":[
            {
                "company":"Ford",
                "price":5000
            },
            {
                "company":"BMW",
                "price":7500
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name":"Josy",
        "cars":[
            {
                "company":"Ford",
                "price":3000
            },
            {
                "company":"BMW",
                "price":5500
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

In the first step I want to add additional Data into my Array Cars and this works fine for me:

```
db.user.updateMany(
    {}, 
    {$set:{"cars.$[].isPremium":false}}
)
```

But now I want to update isPremium to true if the price is higher 3500

```
db.user.updateMany(
    {cars : {$elemMatch:{price:{$gt:3500}}} }, 
    {$set:{"cars.$[].isPremium":true}}
)
```

But this does not work, because the Ford of Josy with a Price of 3000 is set to premium but the price is not > 3500. So what went wront ?

Comment: From the [doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/#id1): `The all positional operator $[] indicates that the update operator should modify all elements in the specified array field.`  Did you mean to use `$[<identifier>]`(https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/#up._S_[<identifier>])?

Answer (score 0):

Solution #1: Try below query after you initialize `isPremium` fields with `false` value:

```js
db.user.updateMany(
    {
        cars: { $elemMatch: { price: { $gt: 3500 } } }
    },
    {
        $set: {
            "cars.$[obj].isPremium": true
        }
    },
    {
        arrayFilters: [
            {
                "obj.price": { $gt: 3500 }
            }
        ]
    }
)
```

Solution #2: No need of your first update query (i.e., initializing `isPremium` with `false`).

```js
db.user.updateMany(
  {
    cars: { $elemMatch: { price: { $gt: 3500 } } }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      "cars.$[premium].isPremium": true,
      "cars.$[nonPremium].isPremium": false
    }
  },
  {
    arrayFilters: [
      {
        "premium.price": { $gt: 3500 }
      },
      {
        "nonPremium.price": { $lte: 3500 }
      }
    ]
  }
)
```